# History.go(-1) does not work in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a chrome extension that goes back to a certain site. But history.go(-1);The syntax is not working Why?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
code: 'document.URL;'
}, function (domain) {
var google = 'https://www.google.co.kr/';
if (domain == google) {
    history.go(-1);
}
else
    alert('not google')


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.mhwdb.kr/main/apis/monsters',
    // data: {
    //     url: domain
    // },
    // dataType: 'json',
    success: function(success){
        document.getElementById('url').innerHTML = success;
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})


})
```

Comment: The extension page (like browserAction popup or background script's page) is a separate page, not related to the web page - your `history.go` runs in the extension page so it does nothing. You need to put the entire code inside `code` string (or as a separate file), which is executed in the web page as a content script.

Comment: Thank you. Your advice was very helpful.